# A theorem in J.F. Dat's number theory notes about the discriminant of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

J. F. Dat's lecture notes on number theory can be found [here](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Ejean-francois.dat/enseignement/TNM2/TNM2.pdf).

I would like to understand the contents of Subsection 2.4.4 of his notes, however I don't speak French.

[image]

Above is a screenshot of the start of the section as well as the statement of his Proposition. In particular, I'd like to understand what the proposition states as well as it's proof.

I am looking for an exact statement and proof of this proposition in English. I'd be happy with some references to some equivalent English-language notes, or alternatively with a proof if someone can supply one as an answer.

Comment: It aims at defining/constructing $Disc(f)$ for $f\in A[x]$ monic with $A$ any ring and states that it is also the determinant of the multiplication by $f'(x)$ in $A[x]/(f(x))$ (which is $\cong A^{\deg(f)}$ as $A$-module so the multiplication by $f'$ can be identified with a matrix $\in M_{\deg(f)}(A)$). The $\Sigma_j$ are certainly the elementary symmetric polynomials in the $X_i$. The core idea is that it suffices to check for each $n$ the case $A=\Bbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ and $f(X)=\prod_{i=1}^n (X-X_i)$ (perhaps you already encountered this idea in the proof of Cayley Hamilton)

Comment: Thanks for stating the statement of the theorem in English. This is very helpful. I'm still looking for a translation of the proof. I'm a little confused by this universal argument, I don't understand what 'universal' means here. If you'd like I can add a bounty to this question in a few days time.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a version of this result with proof as Proposition $2.4.23$ on page $17$ in my lecture notes on [algebraic number theory](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_71_ant.pdf).
The notes are in English (and also available in German if needed). Of course you can also find this result in many other books or lecture notes on ANT.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at your notes.

Comment: Okay I had a look, and my concern is that in Dat's notes there seems to be a bit more going on. I'd like to understand what exactly is being done in that proof with those epsilon morphisms, and what 'universal' means in this context. It appears to me that your proof is not exactly what is in Dat's notes.

Comment: For example in the French version there's something about factorizing X^n - 2 which is not mentioned in your notes.

Comment: @gen Yes, you are right, the proof is a little bit different. But it is also easier, which is perhaps also good. If you really want a $1-1$ translation, then use the google translator, for example.

Comment: I tried running Google Translate on those two pages, but it didn't do much. I guess my question is this: is there anything done in the French proof in addition to what is done in your proof? Is it more general in some sense or something?

Comment: I wouldn't worry so much about the proof. The statement is important, because it is a standard result with several applications. There are several different proofs available in English. So why would you need this proof in a language which you don't know?